# Is it possible to use relative paths for scope, start_url and id in webmanifest.json?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-manifest

Let's say we have a web application which is available through different environments:

```
nightly.my-app.com
test.my-app.com
my-app.com
```

Using `webmanifest.json` we want to identify each version of our app, but we don't want to create a different webmanifest for each build. So we used these values:

```
"scope": "./",
"start_url": "./",
"id": "./",
```

My questions are:

*Are these values valid? Will the browser/ device automatically resolve all values to the actual URL of the app?*

Comment: apart from `id` (which I do not use in my manifest) I use `"start_url": "/", "scope": "/"` without issue

Answer (score 0):

When you define `scope` all the paths will be relative to that.

referring to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope):

> The scope member is a string that defines the navigation scope of this web application's application context. It restricts what web pages can be viewed while the manifest is applied. If the user navigates outside the scope, it reverts to a normal web page inside a browser tab or window.

It also says:

> If the scope is a relative URL, the base URL will be the URL of the manifest.

So don't worry. this is legit and will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. This however is only about `scope`. Are the other values and especially `id` set accordingly to the value of `scope` by the device/ browser then?

Comment: @lampshade as I know all the valid keys in `manifest.json` file are described in the link I provided in the answer and `id` is not one of them.